# VueJs How to remember input data in the forms even after previous/next page and back to form page?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am a newible to VueJs
I would like to use Vue2 to create a Vue validation form

Here is the code I have written to perform a Vue validation form
https://jsfiddle.net/vzx07pk3/

index

```
<div id="app">
      <label for="username">Name</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" v-bind:class="{ 'is-invalid': usernameError }" v-model="username" placeholder="Username"/>
      <div class="invalid-feedback" style="color:red">{{ userErrMsg }}</div>

       <br><br>
 

      <label for="">E-Mail</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" v-bind:class="{ 'is-invalid': emailError }" v-model="email" placeholder="Email"/>
      <div class="invalid-feedback" style="color:red">{{ emailErrMsg }}</div>
      <br><br>
    </div>
```

Js file:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        username: '',
        usernameError: false,
        userErrMsg: '',
        email: '',
        emailError: false,
        emailErrMsg: ''
    },
    watch: {
        username: function () {
            var isText = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;
            if (!isText.test(this.username)) {
                this.usernameError = true;
                this.userErrMsg = 'Only letters and white space allowed ';
            }
            else if (this.username.length > 10) {
                this.usernameError = true;
                this.userErrMsg = 'MaxLength 10';
            }
            else {
                this.usernameError = false;
                this.userErrMsg = '';
            }
        },
        email: function () {
            var isMail = /^\w+((-\w+)|(\.\w+))*\@[A-Za-z0-9]+((\.|-)[A-Za-z0-9]+)*\.[A-Za-z]+$/;
            if (!isMail.test(this.email)) {
                this.emailError = true;
                this.emailErrMsg = 'Invalid email format';
            }
            else {
                this.emailError = false;
                this.emailErrMsg = '';
            }
        }
    }
});
```

but When I click the previous or next page, then back to index.html form page
The input field is auto-remove.

How to remember input data in the forms even after the previous/next page?

Should I use `localStorage` to remember the input value????
such as

```
mounted:function() {
    if (!!window.MSInputMethodContext && !!document.documentMode) {
          window.addEventListener('hashchange', this.hashChangeHandler);
        }
     if (localStorage.username) {
      this.username = localStorage.username;     
     }
    if (localStorage.email) {
      this.email = localStorage.email;     
     }
}
```

Is it the best way to remember input data in the forms even after the previous /next page then back/return to index.html form page????

Thank you very much

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#keep-alive-with-Dynamic-Components

Answer (score 1):

You can use keep-alive to remember your input data like this:

```
<keep-alive>
  your Component
</keep-alive>
```